# Database-pages * Sub-applications * Multi-location * multi-language: how does this work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, localization, globalization

I'm developing (.NET MVC) a large website which has the following specifications:

- Database pages (HTML editors)
- Sub applications (/products, /search, /user-area (more mixed db-pages & apps))
- Multi location (both db-pages & apps)
- Multi language (all: db-pages, apps & multi-location)

I have problems with the following:

1. `Routes`. Do I include `location` and/or `language`? I cannot just prefix or suffix EVERY url? (i somehow want location (and maybe language) to be put in the url for search engine crawling, not sure where to go on this...)
2. Project-management. How do I store `application-resources` (`language` & `location` specific content)?
3. SiteMap 'management'. I currently store every page in the `db` using a parent-child fk. I have my own `sitemapprovider` which uses this data. I also `store every url` of those pages in the db (based on page title and parent-url), because users should be able to generate (multi-level) database pages. If feels as if i'm doing double work here (storing urls and maintaining a routefile..?). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes I can
2. Store in db
3. Store route information in database with pages, automate routemapping